# Cloud Spanner Integration With Liquibase Failure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I am having issues trying to get Liquibase to integrate with Spanner.

I am trying to leverage the liquibase maven plugin and the community supported liquibase-spanner extension. Unfortunately, when i run a mvn liquibase:update command on a new database, i get the following error.

[image]

My pom.xml file looks as follows.

```
<groupId>XXXXXX/groupId>
<artifactId>spanner-data-model</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.liquibase.version>4.3.1</maven.liquibase.version>
    <liquibase.version>1.0.1</liquibase.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.liquibase.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.cloudspannerecosystem</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-spanner</artifactId>
                    <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My liquibase.properties file looks as follows.

```
changeLogFile=/path/to/file/db.changelog-master.yaml
driver=com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcDriver
url=jdbc:cloudspanner:/projects/X/instances/X/databases/X
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong ? Appreciate your inputs and ideas!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is caused by a missing transitive dependency in the JDBC driver. Would you mind trying to add the following dependency to your pom file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-spanner-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Edit: This problem is fixed in version 1.0.2 of the spanner-liquibase library.